# spring.resources.static-locations not working with devtools

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project with the following structure (just like [spring.io](https://github.com/spring-io/sagan)):

```
├── frontend
│   ├── dist
│   |   ├── app.js
│   |   ├── vendor.js
│   |   ├── style.css
│   |   ├── index.html
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── src
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── pom.xml
├── site
│   ├── src
│   ├── pom.xml
```

`frontend` is a NodeJS project and `site` is a Spring Boot project.

All files inside `frontend/dist` (including html) are autogenerated by webpack. In order to access
them from Spring Boot app I've configured development profile.

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  profiles: development
  resources:
    static-locations:
      - file:../frontend/dist/
```

All works just fine. But when I add [spring-boot-devtools](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-devtools) into the site project classpath I get 404 for any file inside `dist` folder.

```
http://localhost:8080/ -> 404
http://localhost:8080/app.js -> 404
```

Again, no devtools - no problem.

Also if I replace static-locations with addResourceHandlers it works too (no matter with or without devtools).

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("file:/full/path/to/frontend/dist/");
}
```

Is this a devtools bug or my fault?

---

**UPDATE:**

Ok thanks to @AndyWilkinson I've figured out the cause of the problem. I work in IntelliJ and use run configurations to set env variables. Here is the resulting command line:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -bla-bla-bla -Didea.version=2017.1.3 -T 2 -Dspring.profiles.active=dev spring-boot:run
```

But if devtools is in the project classpath Spring Boot ignores them:

```
Could not find key 'spring.profiles.active' in any property source
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

Now if I simply remove devtools from pom.xml

```
The following profiles are active: dev
Activated profiles dev
```

... wow, it works again.

The possible workaround is to set active profile directly through application.yml.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev

---

spring:
  profiles: dev
  resources:
    static-locations:
      - file:../frontend/dist/
```

.. but i don't like it because it's inconvenient.

So because devtools is such a pain I think I'll prefer to use F5 as before.

Comment: A couple of things to check. 1) Is your development profile active when you are using DevTools? 2) Does it work with a fully-qualified path in application.yml?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem.

I added `spring.resources.static-location=file:../frontend/build` in `application.properties`

Use can also add absolute path

`spring.resources.static-location=file:/User/XYZ/Desktop/frontend/build`

Answer (score 0):

Configure InternalResourceViewResolver to resolve static resources too:

```
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/classes/static/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix("");
    return viewResolver;
}
```